# Data Trigger Will Not Fire

Tags: wpf, triggers, datatrigger, multidatatrigger

I have the following Data Trigger set-up on a Control Template

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsDragged}"
             Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Active}" />
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Unactive}" />
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

Generally it will fire at least once (not always) and at some point will cease.  Some additional interesting notes:

- The same property is set-up in a MultiDataTrigger, this trigger will always fire
- The same storyboards are referenced in another trigger, they continue to run after this trigger fails

Edit: The MultiDataTriggers is set-up as follows:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsActive}"
                   Value="True" />
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsDragged}"
                   Value="False" />
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsInCart}"
                   Value="False" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ShowTag_BeginStoryboard"
                         Storyboard="{StaticResource ShowTag}" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="HideTag_BeginStoryboard"
                         Storyboard="{StaticResource HideTag}" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an educated guess, but I've run into something like this before and it turned out that I needed to stop each storyboard before I started another one, because they were conflicting with each other.

Try adding two [StopStoryboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.stopstoryboard.aspx) actions to your DataTrigger, one to stop the Active storyboard and the other to stop the Unactive storyboard.